# Split hex representation of an integer and save it in a string

Tags: c, split, hex, printf

I am trying to split the hex values of a variable in a string. For this I am using `sprintf`. But I am getting an error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Below is the code which I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char* t1;
char* t2;

int n = 0x23A;

sprintf(t1, "%X", n & 0xFF);
printf("t1 is : %s\n",t1);


sprintf(t2, "%X", (n >> 8) & 0xFF);
printf("t2 is : %s\n",t2);

return 0 ;
}
```

For example I want to split `0x23A`  in `0x02`  and `0x3A`
And I am using two string because my idea is concatenate them in the end to form a single string with `023A`.

Is there any other way to get this output then please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to "split" it when all you have to do is e.g. `printf("%04X", n)`

Comment: You need to allocate space for writing pointed to by `t1`.

Comment: Also, I suggest you make your pointers actually *point* somewhere. Or use arrays instead. Keep in mind to allocate an extra character for the string terminator.

Comment: You are writing to t1 and t2 that aren't allocated and point to some random address, resulting in segfault.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Thank you for your help, your provided solution worked for me.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY and @ Jacek Ślimok   Thanks for your answers. Now I tried by using a string array, instead of the pointer and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an uninitialized pointer, that gives undefined behavior.

Just use a character array, so you have some space for the string:

```
char t1[16];

sprintf(t1, "%X", n & ff);
printf("t1 is '%s'\n", t1);
```

This should print `3A`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also as one of the comments suggested that if we  use `printf("%04X", n)`  then no need to split the values as well.